# How to calculate value of x in (1875+y):(x+y)=165

Tags: arithmetic

I need to solve this equation but every time I get a different result.Ive tried "find out $x$" calculators online but they fail with "error" or "invalid [...]".

The equation is $(1875+y):(x+y)=165$

(I don't know what tags to use for this question)

Comment: What do you mean by : ?

Comment: You have one equation with two unknowns so you cannot expect to find a definite value for $x$.  You could certainly solve for $x$ in terms of $y$.

Comment: @Seth ? means im asking a question

Comment: @user154731 I meant what do you mean by colon?

Comment: user154731 in the case of the comment ? means @seth is asking you a question...

Comment: @Seth : means divided by

Comment: @user154731 Oh, I have never see that before.  Is that standard?

Comment: @Seth Im quite surprised because everyone I know uses : as "divided by", what do you use instead?

Comment: @user154731 usually we use a fraction notation.  Sometimes we use a horizontal bar with a dot above and below which I don't know how to write on my keyboard.  What country are you from?

Comment: @Seth Poland and you?

Comment: @user154731 United States.

Comment: @Seth did you mean ÷ symbol? You can type it by holding left Alt key and typing in 0247 on the numpad.It works only on Windows OS though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{1875+y}{x+y}=165$, so $1875+y=165x+165y$, so $165x=1875-164y$, so $x=\frac{1875-164y}{165}$.

Comment: What is this kind of equation called? (I usually call it find out value of x equation)

Comment: oh ok, thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

The "$:$" sign is for Ratio, it tells how the first quantity relates to the second quantity in terms of amount/units (both the quantities should be measured in the same unit).

$x:y=2:1$ means $x$ is twice as much as $y$, and the ration $x:y$ is calculated by $\frac{x}{y}$, so in this example $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{2}{1}$, we omit $1$, because it does not affect the right hand side.

Your example is $(1875+y):(x+y)=165:1$, which means we are considering $165$ units of $(1875+y)$ per unit of $(x+y)$.

Comment: So ÷ is same as : (think about it)